# Python Power set which has also the letter itself ( recursion )

Tags: python, recursion, subset, combinations, repeat

( This is a code from delftstack, all credit to them ).
I am looking for help to write a code which prints all subsets of a string. I know how to do with subset sum to print all combination \ return list of combinations.
But when I have no subset sum like that, I am in a little pinch.
The code from there:

```
def powerSet(string , index , c):
    if index == len(string):
        print(c)
        return
    powerSet(string, index + 1,
         c + string[index])
    powerSet(string, index + 1, c)

s1 = ["a","b","c"]
index = 0
c = ""
powerSet(s1, index , c)
```

Now, I don't know how to "upgrade" the code so it will give me the ones that has `"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bb", "aa"`, and such... I mean - with repetitions.
I am having problem thinking of a exit condition. I mean, what is my base case?
I cant say if len == 0, it will not be good.

There is a code I create for ABC, it was originally to return a list of all ABC in length of 1~3 with repetition and such:

```
def ABC(num,tempComb,new_list):
    if num == 0:
        new_list.append(tempComb)
        return new_list
    lst = ["A","B","C"]
    take_1=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[0]],new_list)
    dont_take_1 = ABC(num-1, tempComb, new_list)
    take_2=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[1]],new_list)
    take_3=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[2]],new_list)
    return dont_take_1
```

I added the dont_take_1 trying to change it so it will count strings less than 3, like 1 and 2.
it kind of works, but I have here repetition, like, I see ["A"] 3 times or more...
How do I make it so there will be no repetition?

Comment: `ìtertools.product(iterable, repeat=n)` should do the job

Comment: @cards Hi thanks. but we didnt learn iterators or generator.
Plus I need to do it recursively.

Comment: I strongly discourage mixing the algorithm itself with input/output considerations. In other words: **never use `print` instead of `return`**. Write a function to generate the powerset, using either keyword `return` or keyword `yield`, but not using function `print`. Then if you want to print, write another function that calls you function `powerset` and prints the result using function `print`.

Comment: Note that recursion in python can be terribly inefficient. Learning recursion is great, and recursion is great in most programming languages. But recursion sucks in python. So, write your function with recursion to learn about recursion, but not to learn python.

Comment: @Stef I too discourage using print, but that is the question.
Although as you saw in the ABC, I did return, I can just print there I know. I actually dont like printing too, but thanks :)

Comment: @Stef Sadly, all question that is like subsets, the professor asks us to do recursion.
It is not a question of homework, its close to a question I had, but as you said, I want to learn how to do it recursively, as it can help in exercises like knapsack, subsets of kinds, or others.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a help with writing, so will give you few pseudocode pieces that can be helpfull for you.

We will build the results based on some prefix we pass to function. In function we can append all characters to that prefix and run the function with longer prefix. The stop condition would be `len(prefix) == dedicated size`

```
def foo2(characters):
    for dedicated_size in range(max_len):
        foo(characters, "", dedicated_size)

def foo(characters, prefix, dedicated_size):
    # stop when prefix is long enough
    # for every character run the function with longer prefix
```

Comment: Well, the problem is, as said, I dont have a dedicated size... 
let us say I say length is 4 and I have string ["1", "0"], I need to return all combination of 0,1 in length from 0 to length 4 ( all of them ).
not only 0000 1111 and such... 
Thus that solution is not good ( i already solved that question, you may find it in the post actually, with ABC )

Comment: @LearningToCode Then write a function that takes a parameter `size`. And then write a second function that calls the first function with every value of `size`.

Comment: @Stef I still dont understand what it will help, the size? since the size changes, let us say size=4, it will be 1,2,3,4

Comment: @LearningToCode Because you need to know the size of the string you're currently generating. In order to generate strings of all sizes: first generate all strings of size 1; then all strings of size 2: then all strings of size 3; then all strings of size 4. When you're at the step "all strings of size 4" you need to know that you are at this step.So you need a parameter for the size.

Comment: Ahh, I will try and update, seems hard, but I will try :) Thanks